# Pandas: Get Target & Loss Indicators Based on Stock Price Attaining Certain Ratios with Dynamically Changing Base Prices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the dataframe as given:

```
date                            open    high    low    close    volume
28  2021-08-24 10:58:00+05:30   207.5   214.05  206     211.35  850
29  2021-08-24 10:59:00+05:30   211.35  215.15  211.35  214.85  175
30  2021-08-24 11:00:00+05:30   214.85  215.75  212.75  213.9   275
31  2021-08-24 11:01:00+05:30   213.9   214.15  209.75  212.65  975
35  2021-08-24 11:05:00+05:30   217.45  221.95  216.65  218.5   750
36  2021-08-24 11:06:00+05:30   218.5   230.5   218.5   229.3   1775
37  2021-08-24 11:07:00+05:30   229.3   235.05  225     233.4   1900
38  2021-08-24 11:08:00+05:30   233.4   236.45  232.5   233.65  1100
39  2021-08-24 11:09:00+05:30   233.65  236.45  233     234.45  1825
40  2021-08-24 11:10:00+05:30   234.45  236.65  227.1   227.4   1225
41  2021-08-24 11:11:00+05:30   227.4   232.4   227.4   229.7   375
42  2021-08-24 11:12:00+05:30   229.7   229.75  226.9   228.55  350
43  2021-08-24 11:13:00+05:30   227.3   228.9   223.95  224.7   725
44  2021-08-24 11:14:00+05:30   224.2   224.35  221.85  224.1   300
58  2021-08-24 11:28:00+05:30   234.5   246.35  233.4   243.65  4075
59  2021-08-24 11:29:00+05:30   243.65  248.25  241.25  247.85  1075
60  2021-08-24 11:30:00+05:30   247.85  250.6   246.3   248.45  1650
61  2021-08-24 11:31:00+05:30   248.35  248.35  244.3   244.3   7350
62  2021-08-24 11:32:00+05:30   244.3   246.35  243.8   243.95  1450
63  2021-08-24 11:33:00+05:30   243.95  246.5   241.4   241.4   600
64  2021-08-24 11:34:00+05:30   241.4   260     241.4   258     3425
65  2021-08-24 11:35:00+05:30   256.95  266.7   256.45  262.35  5950
66  2021-08-24 11:36:00+05:30   262.35  268.2   261.35  267 5200
67  2021-08-24 11:37:00+05:30   266.75  269.45  264.5   267.45  4175
68  2021-08-24 11:38:00+05:30   267.45  267.45  258.65  260.15  1725
69  2021-08-24 11:39:00+05:30   260.15  265.5   258.15  263.4   1875
70  2021-08-24 11:40:00+05:30   263.4   263.9   260.05  260.7   1950
71  2021-08-24 11:41:00+05:30   260     260.9   253.65  254.95  1350
72  2021-08-24 11:42:00+05:30   255.4   255.4   251.6   253.3   1100
88  2021-08-24 11:58:00+05:30   277.5   278.9   274.35  276.05  500
89  2021-08-24 11:59:00+05:30   276.1   285     276.1   285     1000
90  2021-08-24 12:00:00+05:30   285.7   286.8   276     279.2   2100
91  2021-08-24 12:01:00+05:30   279.2   282.2   277.95  282.2   650
92  2021-08-24 12:02:00+05:30   282.2   286.5   282 282.15  1500
93  2021-08-24 12:03:00+05:30   282.15  291.35  282.15  290.6   2425
94  2021-08-24 12:04:00+05:30   290.6   292.5   287.75  288.15  925
95  2021-08-24 12:05:00+05:30   288.15  288.95  282.55  286.1   2300
96  2021-08-24 12:06:00+05:30   286.1   291.1   286.1   291.1   350
97  2021-08-24 12:07:00+05:30   292.2   298     288.4   298     2400
98  2021-08-24 12:08:00+05:30   299 301.8       294.4   296     2900
99  2021-08-24 12:09:00+05:30   296 299.55      296     299.55  1100
100 2021-08-24 12:10:00+05:30   299.55  300     295.4   296.95  825
101 2021-08-24 12:11:00+05:30   296.95  297.65  292     292     475
128 2021-08-24 12:38:00+05:30   310.55  314.4   308     314.4   1150
129 2021-08-24 12:39:00+05:30   314.4   317.1   311.05  315.3   700
130 2021-08-24 12:40:00+05:30   316.8   331     316.55  330.4   5950
131 2021-08-24 12:41:00+05:30   329.7   333     326.8   330.45  4675
132 2021-08-24 12:42:00+05:30   330.45  330.45  323.15  327.9   1625
133 2021-08-24 12:43:00+05:30   326.7   327.7   320.95  324 1475
134 2021-08-24 12:44:00+05:30   323.4   326     317.9   324.95  1450
135 2021-08-24 12:45:00+05:30   324.95  331     321.65  330 1175
136 2021-08-24 12:46:00+05:30   330     331.2   324.9   326.85  1400
137 2021-08-24 12:47:00+05:30   326.9   327.05  322.25  326.6   1325
138 2021-08-24 12:48:00+05:30   326.6   326.6   321.1   322.2   625
151 2021-08-24 13:01:00+05:30   337.85  337.85  331.95  334.2   725
152 2021-08-24 13:02:00+05:30   331.8   332.5   322.2   324.65  1550
163 2021-08-24 13:13:00+05:30   328.65  329.75  327.35  329 800
164 2021-08-24 13:14:00+05:30   329     332.15  325 325 300
165 2021-08-24 13:15:00+05:30   325     325 316.5   316.5   850
166 2021-08-24 13:16:00+05:30   316.5   325 316.5   325 225
167 2021-08-24 13:17:00+05:30   325     326.95  323.2   325 375
168 2021-08-24 13:18:00+05:30   325     327.85  323.4   326.05  875
169 2021-08-24 13:19:00+05:30   326.05  330.9   326.05  326.95  475
170 2021-08-24 13:20:00+05:30   326.95  327 324.15  325.9   350
171 2021-08-24 13:21:00+05:30   324.15  328.1   324.15  328.1   300
172 2021-08-24 13:22:00+05:30   328.1   338.05  328.1   337.55  550
173 2021-08-24 13:23:00+05:30   336     345.8   336 345.05  3025
174 2021-08-24 13:24:00+05:30   344.35  345.05  339.55  342.75  2125
175 2021-08-24 13:25:00+05:30   342.75  342.75  338.15  339.95  800
176 2021-08-24 13:26:00+05:30   339.95  340.9   337 340 825
177 2021-08-24 13:27:00+05:30   340     342 336.15  342 1000
178 2021-08-24 13:28:00+05:30   342     345.6   341.1   342.65  1500
179 2021-08-24 13:29:00+05:30   342.65  345.85  341 344.1   950
180 2021-08-24 13:30:00+05:30   344.1   344.1   334.6   334.6   1575
181 2021-08-24 13:31:00+05:30   337     338.15  333.95  333.95  650
202 2021-08-24 13:52:00+05:30   335.4   340.65  335.4   340.4   1700
203 2021-08-24 13:53:00+05:30   340.4   341.2   339 340 1400
204 2021-08-24 13:54:00+05:30   340     346.15  339.3   345.25  925
205 2021-08-24 13:55:00+05:30   345.6   347.9   342.3   342.3   1500
206 2021-08-24 13:56:00+05:30   341.35  342.3   339.2   339.2   825
207 2021-08-24 13:57:00+05:30   338.25  345.1   336.4   343.3   2050
208 2021-08-24 13:58:00+05:30   343.3   346.7   340.1   343.85  650
209 2021-08-24 13:59:00+05:30   343.2   343.85  339 340 925
210 2021-08-24 14:00:00+05:30   340     342.35  338.95  338.95  625
211 2021-08-24 14:01:00+05:30   338.95  344.4   338.75  339.2   975
212 2021-08-24 14:02:00+05:30   339.2   346.3   339.2   345.1   800
213 2021-08-24 14:03:00+05:30   345.1   345.9   340.35  343.95  450
214 2021-08-24 14:04:00+05:30   343.95  344 341.8   344 775
224 2021-08-24 14:14:00+05:30   344.15  344.9   337.7   344.35  2100
231 2021-08-24 14:21:00+05:30   361.5   367.3   360.05  361.65  5525
232 2021-08-24 14:22:00+05:30   361.65  367.3   360.9   365 2800
233 2021-08-24 14:23:00+05:30   365     373.7   364.05  373.6   5625
234 2021-08-24 14:24:00+05:30   372.35  383.7   370.6   382.15  6200
235 2021-08-24 14:25:00+05:30   384.45  387.55  376.85  379.8   4250
236 2021-08-24 14:26:00+05:30   379.8   396.15  379.55  393 3250
237 2021-08-24 14:27:00+05:30   393.6   400 391.55  397 3875
238 2021-08-24 14:28:00+05:30   398.7   398.7   391.7   396.5   4450
239 2021-08-24 14:29:00+05:30   395.65  396.5   392.6   394.75  4800
240 2021-08-24 14:30:00+05:30   394.75  399.15  394.75  397.55  3950
```

In this dataframe I have to add two new columns namely Target and Loss as per the given condition:

1. Initially, we will take the close price from the first row as base close price. Now whenever the `"current close" = 1.03 * "base close"` the row corresponding to that value under the `Target` column should be 1. *Then, the "base close" price is updated to this "current close" attained the target ratio.*
2. Else whenever `"current close" = 0.97 * "base close"` the row corresponding to that value under the `Loss` column should be 1.  (This "base close" could be different from the "base close" for `Target` column.) *Simlarly, the "base close" price is updated to this "current close" attained the loss ratio.*
3. All the close values in the range: `0.97 * "base close(Loss)" <= "current close" <= 1.03 * "base close(Target)"` should be ignored

eg:

1. In the above Dataframe we select "base close" =211.35. Now 1.03 * "base close" =217.69. Since 218.50 > 217.69 hence the row corresponding to that value under `Target` column is set to 1. Hence row no 36 under `Target` column should be 1. 218.50 is now the "base close" for subsequent processing.
2. Now we select "base close"=218.50. Since 1.03*218.50=225.05 . Since 229.3 > 225.05 the row corresponding to that value under the `Target` row is 1. Hence row 36 under loss column is set as 1
3. We continue these calculations till we reach end of frame
4. All the other rows not satisfying the above two conditions under `Target` and `Loss` columns are set as 0

Final Dataframe should look as given:

[image]

Comment: Can you replace your image by plain text data, please?

Comment: @Corralien Did as you asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As clarified by OP, in each row, the base value for calculating the ratio with the current row value is NOT constantly the last row value that we can obtain this base value by `.shift()`.  Instead, this base value is either the value of first row or the previous row value that attained the target ratio. In effect, this base value can be any value from previous rows, depending on its relative value with its previous values.

For this, we have to approach using custom functions so that we can dynamically update the base value for ratio calculation.  We can define 2 functions:

```
def set_Target(close, factor):
    last_val = close.iat[0]
    target_list = []
    for i, val in close.iteritems():
        if (val / last_val) > factor:
            target_list.append(1)
            last_val = val
        else:
            target_list.append(0)
    return target_list


def set_Loss(close, factor):
    last_val = close.iat[0]
    loss_list = []
    for i, val in close.iteritems():
        if (val / last_val) < factor:
            loss_list.append(1)
            last_val = val
        else:
            loss_list.append(0)
    return loss_list
```

Then, we call the custom functions to set up columns `Target` and `Loss`, as follows:

```
df['Target'] = set_Target(df['close'], 1.03)

df['Loss'] = set_Loss(df['close'], 0.97)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

                          date    open    high     low   close  volume  Target  Loss
28   2021-08-24 10:58:00+05:30  207.50  214.05  206.00  211.35     850       0     0
29   2021-08-24 10:59:00+05:30  211.35  215.15  211.35  214.85     175       0     0
30   2021-08-24 11:00:00+05:30  214.85  215.75  212.75  213.90     275       0     0
31   2021-08-24 11:01:00+05:30  213.90  214.15  209.75  212.65     975       0     0
35   2021-08-24 11:05:00+05:30  217.45  221.95  216.65  218.50     750       1     0
36   2021-08-24 11:06:00+05:30  218.50  230.50  218.50  229.30    1775       1     0
37   2021-08-24 11:07:00+05:30  229.30  235.05  225.00  233.40    1900       0     0
38   2021-08-24 11:08:00+05:30  233.40  236.45  232.50  233.65    1100       0     0
39   2021-08-24 11:09:00+05:30  233.65  236.45  233.00  234.45    1825       0     0
40   2021-08-24 11:10:00+05:30  234.45  236.65  227.10  227.40    1225       0     0
41   2021-08-24 11:11:00+05:30  227.40  232.40  227.40  229.70     375       0     0
42   2021-08-24 11:12:00+05:30  229.70  229.75  226.90  228.55     350       0     0
43   2021-08-24 11:13:00+05:30  227.30  228.90  223.95  224.70     725       0     0
44   2021-08-24 11:14:00+05:30  224.20  224.35  221.85  224.10     300       0     0
58   2021-08-24 11:28:00+05:30  234.50  246.35  233.40  243.65    4075       1     0
59   2021-08-24 11:29:00+05:30  243.65  248.25  241.25  247.85    1075       0     0
60   2021-08-24 11:30:00+05:30  247.85  250.60  246.30  248.45    1650       0     0
61   2021-08-24 11:31:00+05:30  248.35  248.35  244.30  244.30    7350       0     0
62   2021-08-24 11:32:00+05:30  244.30  246.35  243.80  243.95    1450       0     0
63   2021-08-24 11:33:00+05:30  243.95  246.50  241.40  241.40     600       0     0
64   2021-08-24 11:34:00+05:30  241.40  260.00  241.40  258.00    3425       1     0
65   2021-08-24 11:35:00+05:30  256.95  266.70  256.45  262.35    5950       0     0
66   2021-08-24 11:36:00+05:30  262.35  268.20  261.35  267.00    5200       1     0
67   2021-08-24 11:37:00+05:30  266.75  269.45  264.50  267.45    4175       0     0
68   2021-08-24 11:38:00+05:30  267.45  267.45  258.65  260.15    1725       0     0
69   2021-08-24 11:39:00+05:30  260.15  265.50  258.15  263.40    1875       0     0
70   2021-08-24 11:40:00+05:30  263.40  263.90  260.05  260.70    1950       0     0
71   2021-08-24 11:41:00+05:30  260.00  260.90  253.65  254.95    1350       0     0
72   2021-08-24 11:42:00+05:30  255.40  255.40  251.60  253.30    1100       0     0
88   2021-08-24 11:58:00+05:30  277.50  278.90  274.35  276.05     500       1     0
89   2021-08-24 11:59:00+05:30  276.10  285.00  276.10  285.00    1000       1     0
90   2021-08-24 12:00:00+05:30  285.70  286.80  276.00  279.20    2100       0     0
91   2021-08-24 12:01:00+05:30  279.20  282.20  277.95  282.20     650       0     0
92   2021-08-24 12:02:00+05:30  282.20  286.50  282.00  282.15    1500       0     0
93   2021-08-24 12:03:00+05:30  282.15  291.35  282.15  290.60    2425       0     0
94   2021-08-24 12:04:00+05:30  290.60  292.50  287.75  288.15     925       0     0
95   2021-08-24 12:05:00+05:30  288.15  288.95  282.55  286.10    2300       0     0
96   2021-08-24 12:06:00+05:30  286.10  291.10  286.10  291.10     350       0     0
97   2021-08-24 12:07:00+05:30  292.20  298.00  288.40  298.00    2400       1     0
98   2021-08-24 12:08:00+05:30  299.00  301.80  294.40  296.00    2900       0     0
99   2021-08-24 12:09:00+05:30  296.00  299.55  296.00  299.55    1100       0     0
100  2021-08-24 12:10:00+05:30  299.55  300.00  295.40  296.95     825       0     0
101  2021-08-24 12:11:00+05:30  296.95  297.65  292.00  292.00     475       0     0
128  2021-08-24 12:38:00+05:30  310.55  314.40  308.00  314.40    1150       1     0
129  2021-08-24 12:39:00+05:30  314.40  317.10  311.05  315.30     700       0     0
130  2021-08-24 12:40:00+05:30  316.80  331.00  316.55  330.40    5950       1     0
131  2021-08-24 12:41:00+05:30  329.70  333.00  326.80  330.45    4675       0     0
132  2021-08-24 12:42:00+05:30  330.45  330.45  323.15  327.90    1625       0     0
133  2021-08-24 12:43:00+05:30  326.70  327.70  320.95  324.00    1475       0     0
134  2021-08-24 12:44:00+05:30  323.40  326.00  317.90  324.95    1450       0     0
135  2021-08-24 12:45:00+05:30  324.95  331.00  321.65  330.00    1175       0     0
136  2021-08-24 12:46:00+05:30  330.00  331.20  324.90  326.85    1400       0     0
137  2021-08-24 12:47:00+05:30  326.90  327.05  322.25  326.60    1325       0     0
138  2021-08-24 12:48:00+05:30  326.60  326.60  321.10  322.20     625       0     0
151  2021-08-24 13:01:00+05:30  337.85  337.85  331.95  334.20     725       0     0
152  2021-08-24 13:02:00+05:30  331.80  332.50  322.20  324.65    1550       0     0
163  2021-08-24 13:13:00+05:30  328.65  329.75  327.35  329.00     800       0     0
164  2021-08-24 13:14:00+05:30  329.00  332.15  325.00  325.00     300       0     0
165  2021-08-24 13:15:00+05:30  325.00  325.00  316.50  316.50     850       0     0
166  2021-08-24 13:16:00+05:30  316.50  325.00  316.50  325.00     225       0     0
167  2021-08-24 13:17:00+05:30  325.00  326.95  323.20  325.00     375       0     0
168  2021-08-24 13:18:00+05:30  325.00  327.85  323.40  326.05     875       0     0
169  2021-08-24 13:19:00+05:30  326.05  330.90  326.05  326.95     475       0     0
170  2021-08-24 13:20:00+05:30  326.95  327.00  324.15  325.90     350       0     0
171  2021-08-24 13:21:00+05:30  324.15  328.10  324.15  328.10     300       0     0
172  2021-08-24 13:22:00+05:30  328.10  338.05  328.10  337.55     550       0     0
173  2021-08-24 13:23:00+05:30  336.00  345.80  336.00  345.05    3025       1     0
174  2021-08-24 13:24:00+05:30  344.35  345.05  339.55  342.75    2125       0     0
175  2021-08-24 13:25:00+05:30  342.75  342.75  338.15  339.95     800       0     0
176  2021-08-24 13:26:00+05:30  339.95  340.90  337.00  340.00     825       0     0
177  2021-08-24 13:27:00+05:30  340.00  342.00  336.15  342.00    1000       0     0
178  2021-08-24 13:28:00+05:30  342.00  345.60  341.10  342.65    1500       0     0
179  2021-08-24 13:29:00+05:30  342.65  345.85  341.00  344.10     950       0     0
180  2021-08-24 13:30:00+05:30  344.10  344.10  334.60  334.60    1575       0     0
181  2021-08-24 13:31:00+05:30  337.00  338.15  333.95  333.95     650       0     0
202  2021-08-24 13:52:00+05:30  335.40  340.65  335.40  340.40    1700       0     0
203  2021-08-24 13:53:00+05:30  340.40  341.20  339.00  340.00    1400       0     0
204  2021-08-24 13:54:00+05:30  340.00  346.15  339.30  345.25     925       0     0
205  2021-08-24 13:55:00+05:30  345.60  347.90  342.30  342.30    1500       0     0
206  2021-08-24 13:56:00+05:30  341.35  342.30  339.20  339.20     825       0     0
207  2021-08-24 13:57:00+05:30  338.25  345.10  336.40  343.30    2050       0     0
208  2021-08-24 13:58:00+05:30  343.30  346.70  340.10  343.85     650       0     0
209  2021-08-24 13:59:00+05:30  343.20  343.85  339.00  340.00     925       0     0
210  2021-08-24 14:00:00+05:30  340.00  342.35  338.95  338.95     625       0     0
211  2021-08-24 14:01:00+05:30  338.95  344.40  338.75  339.20     975       0     0
212  2021-08-24 14:02:00+05:30  339.20  346.30  339.20  345.10     800       0     0
213  2021-08-24 14:03:00+05:30  345.10  345.90  340.35  343.95     450       0     0
214  2021-08-24 14:04:00+05:30  343.95  344.00  341.80  344.00     775       0     0
224  2021-08-24 14:14:00+05:30  344.15  344.90  337.70  344.35    2100       0     0
231  2021-08-24 14:21:00+05:30  361.50  367.30  360.05  361.65    5525       1     0
232  2021-08-24 14:22:00+05:30  361.65  367.30  360.90  365.00    2800       0     0
233  2021-08-24 14:23:00+05:30  365.00  373.70  364.05  373.60    5625       1     0
234  2021-08-24 14:24:00+05:30  372.35  383.70  370.60  382.15    6200       0     0
235  2021-08-24 14:25:00+05:30  384.45  387.55  376.85  379.80    4250       0     0
236  2021-08-24 14:26:00+05:30  379.80  396.15  379.55  393.00    3250       1     0
237  2021-08-24 14:27:00+05:30  393.60  400.00  391.55  397.00    3875       0     0
238  2021-08-24 14:28:00+05:30  398.70  398.70  391.70  396.50    4450       0     0
239  2021-08-24 14:29:00+05:30  395.65  396.50  392.60  394.75    4800       0     0
240  2021-08-24 14:30:00+05:30  394.75  399.15  394.75  397.55    3950       0     0
```

Comment: @ SeaBean Your solution works but there is a small bug. I have edited the question to reflect that bug

Comment: @Python_Coder  Want to clarify what's the base value to compare in each row?  Not the previous row ?  Is it always the first `Close` price or how is the base price changed ?

Comment: @ SeaBean. The base price changes everytime. First initially we select the Buy.close.iloc[0]. We apply the conditions as given and then check whether it has hit target or loss. In our case it hits the target as 1.03* close=217.69. We do not find 217.69 in the df but we find 218.50 hence row 35 under target column is set to 1. Now for further calculation we take close=218.50 and not 211.35. Now we again see that it hits the target as 1.03* close=225.05. Now by same logic row 36 is set to 1. Now close=229.3 is selected

Comment: @Python_Coder  Ok, got it clear now.  Let me think of it.

Comment: @Python_Coder  See my edit above.  Updated solution to cater the clarified requirement.

Comment: @ SeaBean This is what I expected. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: @ SeaBean. One minor mistake in the function set_Loss instead of  target_list.append(1) it should be loss_list.append(1). Similarly target_list.append(0) should be  loss_list.append(0). and all target variables should be replaced by loss variables. We should use two different columns for two different purposes I tried to edit your answer. But I cant

Comment: @Python_Coder  Haha, thanks for catching this.  Anyway, it's the name of internal variable names.  Should not affect the result.  Still the same result.

Comment: Yea that is true :)

Comment: @Python_Coder  Anyway, amended it.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly the conditions to Choose NaN or 1 but let me give you a quick hint how to make it using append first open two empty lists

`Target = [] Loss = []`

I would open two appends as `append` inside a for loop and add all if else loops for each condition

```
for x in range len(df):
    if df[close] "add your condition":
         Target.append[1]
         Loss.append['Nan']
     else: 
         Target.append[1]
         Loss.append['Nan']
```

after that convert the list to a dataFrame and use `pd.concat` to join it to the main Datafrme df

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative using `pct_change` and `loc`:

```
pc = df['close'].pct_change()
pcu = pc.gt(0.02)
pcd = pc.lt(-0.01)
df.loc[pcu[pcu].index, 'Target'] = 1
df.loc[pcd[pcd].index, 'Loss'] = 1
```

*NB. the values returned by `pct_change` are in the form "0.02" where you want "1.02" (minus 1)*

output:

```
      close  Target  Loss
1   1543.95     NaN   NaN
2   1740.60     1.0   NaN
3   1740.60     NaN   NaN
4   1740.60     NaN   NaN
5   1740.60     NaN   NaN
6   1740.60     NaN   NaN
7   1740.60     NaN   NaN
8   1740.60     NaN   NaN
9   1740.60     NaN   NaN
10  1740.60     NaN   NaN
11  1740.60     NaN   NaN
12  1740.60     NaN   NaN
13   873.60     NaN   1.0
14   881.05     NaN   NaN
15   864.05     NaN   1.0
16   928.35     1.0   NaN
17   921.65     NaN   NaN
18   813.80     NaN   1.0
19   732.55     NaN   1.0
20   748.50     1.0   NaN
```

Comment: None I am using this on the Mobile device might have pressed it as an accident. Thanks bdw :)

Comment: @ mozway I also tried your solution but your solution also gives the bug as explained